# Difference between two columns with date and time imported from a CSV file

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, csv

I have to import a CSV file into a SQL Server table.
The CSV has 8 columns and 2 of them are date and time values.

In my SQL table I have a column which store the difference between 2 the columns of CSV file.

I am unable to check if the cell is empty or not.

My code follows:

```
 protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string csvPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(csvPath);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[8] { new DataColumn("basid", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("EmployeeName", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Designation",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("OfficeLocation",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Division",typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Intime",typeof(DateTime)),
            new DataColumn("Outtime",typeof(DateTime)),
            new DataColumn("timedifference",typeof(DateTime))

        });
        string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);
        foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
                int i = 0;
                foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
                {
                    if (i == 7)
                    {
                        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = ((DateTime)(dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i - 1]) - (DateTime)(dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i - 2]));
                    }
                    else {
                        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
                    }

                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                //Set the database table name.
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.basids";
                con.Open();
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow ! Please read the help on [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: What is the problem ? Can you edit your question and add a sample of the CSV file ?

Comment: given the sample data. I have 8 columns in CSV file. Data of CSV is to inserted in database table. I am unable to check that if the cell is empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

### Understanding

Importing from a CSV file (or any other file that does not conform to the *Relational Model*), is not a problem.  You need to understand that the file is not, and never will be, a Relational table.  At best it is a file with good field types, at worst one with hopeless field types.

- You may create a **raw table** in the database, for convenience, that is, in order to use SQL on it
- At best, the fields in the file have reliable datatypes, thus the raw table may have SQL Datatypes.
- At worst, the Datatypes in the raw table are all `CHAR(x)`.
- In any case, the columns in the raw table must match the import file exactly.
- Usually, such raw tables do not have an Index, they are just `Heaps`.
- Your app code will not query the raw tables, they are manipulated on by the **Import** code, only.
- `DataTable dt` is such a raw table.

The **Relational table** (or tables) that are in the Relational database are quite a different animal.  They are properly designed, Normalised, and compliant with the *Relational Model*.  Relational tables have Primary Keys that are "made up from the data", and may have additional Unique Keys.  The datatypes are "tight", and disallow illegal values.

- Your app code will query the Relational tables, only.
- Hence it is quite normal, that one CSV file (or import file or raw table) translates to more than one Relational table.

Therefore **Import** is always a two-step process:

1. First, just import the CSV file into the **raw table**, which has been suitably set up for that act.

   - You have not asked the question, but if I were loading this CSV file into a raw table, I wouldn't bother with all that middle-tier code, I would use the MS SQL `bcp` utility.
2. Second, INSERT-SELECT from the raw table into the **Relational table(s)**.

   - In this step, the SELECT will transform the raw fields into proper Datatypes, and perform any checking that is required.
   - In order to ensure that the FK Constraints do not fail, the Reference tables must be populated before the data tables.  For populating the Reference tables (not the raw file), eg. Operator, the code may be:

```
INSERT Operator
    SELECT ... 
        FROM RawTable.Operator
        WHERE RawTable.Operator NOT IN (
            SELECT Operator
                FROM Operator
            )
```

**ETL** stands for **E**xtract; **T**ransform; **L**oad.  It is never Load only.

---

### Problem

1. You have a raw table, only.  And you think it is a Relational table.  It is not.
2. You have no Relational tables.
3. Third, ...

> I am unable to check if the cell is empty or not.

Yes, you can.  After importing the CSV file into a raw table (possibly `DataTable dt`, or `BAS_Raw` below), which is step [1], in step [2], use ordinary SQL checks and transformations.

```
SELECT
        ...
        [Hours] = CASE OutTime
            WHEN NULL THEN CONVERT( TIME, "00:00" )
            ELSE           CONVERT( TIME, OutTime - InTime )
            END
        ...
    FROM BAS_Raw
```

### Relational Database

The solution is, of course, to:

1. implement a Relational database, that has both:

   - Relational tables for all app queries, and
   - the raw table for the importation only
2. understand the two-step process that is required for importation of CSV files, including any checking and data transformation, as required.

[image: AmitTA]

#### Note • Content

- I have no idea what `basid` is, therefore I have not modelled it.  If you declare what it is, I will model it.
- the time difference or hours worked does not need to be stored, because it is easily **derived** (OutTime minus InTime).

#### Note • Notation

- All my data models are rendered in **[IDEF1X](https://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/)**, the Standard for modelling Relational databases since 1993
- My **[IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf)** is essential reading for beginners or novices, wrt a Relational database.